# Does reload vimrc from a terminal give an error?

Tags: vim, vimrc

When I reload .vimrc from vim, it doesn't give any sign of error.

```
:so %
```

But when I use terminal to reload, it gives an error.

```
$ source ~/.vimrc
```

Does it suppose to give an error? Or I'm not supposed to source it from a terminal?

I use Mavericks + iTerm + oh-my-zsh.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `~/.vimrc` file contains settings and customizations for Vim, written in *Vimscript* (also known as *Ex commands*, based on the vi-mode they're entered). A shell (like Bash running in your terminal) cannot understand those commands, and therefore gives you errors. (Likewise, `:source ~/.bashrc` would give you errors in Vim. You also don't source other *RC files* like `~/.gitconfig` or `~/.mailrc` and expect that to work.)

So, though `:source` and `$ source` are commands with the same name, they only apply to their corresponding contexts.